# Error with \RequirePackage in a class file

Tags: babel, documentclass-writing

I am trying to use the command `\RequirePackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}` in my own class (i.e, my .cls file) but the following error occurs:

> Command \labelenumi already defined.

A temporary solution that I found is use the command `\RequirePackage[spanish,english,es-tabla]{babel}`, but this produces changes in the titles of the ToC, LoF and LoT, because I changed with

```
\addto\captionsspanish{
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{contenido}}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{%
 \renewcommand{\listfigurename}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{lista de figuras}}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{%
 \renewcommand{\listtablename}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{lista de tablas}}%
}
```

There is some solution?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: A mwe of myclass.cls and test.tex

> myclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2017/04/15]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2018/06/09 Standard LaTeX document class]
\let\labelenumi\relax
\RequirePackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
... %here the code is the same of the book class
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,final,openright}
\ProcessOptions
... %here the code is the same of the book class
\endinput
```

> test.tex

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
... % other packages

\addto\captionsspanish{%
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{contenido}}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{%
 \renewcommand{\listfigurename}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{lista de figuras}}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{%
 \renewcommand{\listtablename}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{lista de tablas}}%
}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Edit: It works with

> myclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2017/04/15]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2018/06/09 Standard LaTeX document class]
... %here the code is the same of the book class
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,final,openright}
\ProcessOptions
... %here the code is the same of the book class
\RequirePackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\addto\captionsspanish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{contenido}}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{%
 \renewcommand{\listfigurename}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{lista de figuras}}%
}
\addto\captionsspanish{%
 \renewcommand{\listtablename}%
    {\center\normalsize\MakeUppercase{lista de tablas}}%
}
\endinput
```

Comment: a command `\let\labelenumi\relax` just before your call to `babel` could do the trick...

Comment: thanks for answering. I tried your suggestion: `\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,final,openright}
\ProcessOptions
\let\labelenumi\relax
\RequirePackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}` but the error is the same

Comment: Can you please add a mwe with filecontents?

Comment: I'll try, I'm still a little newbie...

Comment: It is perfect now. The problem is that the command have to be given somehow between the two options of babel

Comment: I do not understand you :(, please you explain me

Comment: I mean that your MWE is perfect for people to help you and I am trying. I thought that could not call babel with these two options and had to do something inside babel..  But still looking for the problem

Comment: Try `\RequirePackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}` just before `\endinput` in your cls. Edit: Sorry but worked on a wrong example.. You edited in between...

Comment: works! I edited the post with a MWE with your suggestion. I would like to know why it worked in this way...

Comment: `\RequirePackage` is usually called in `.sty` files (in packages). Packages has to be called after `\documentclass`... And thus, packages (like babel here) will take care of previous defined commands, but documentclass has no reason to do it and has no checks about it

Comment: If you checked everything and works fine, I can make it an answer... But my suggestion is to not use babel inside your `.cls` file if no needed there, but just as `\usepackage` in your main file.

Comment: Another solution is to use the `\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-tabla}{babel}` command, but I thought it was best to include babel in the `.cls` file. So, if I use a .sty file, is better?

Comment: You didn't made any change in the cls that needed an edit in the `cls`. You could just add these in your preamble. So, yes... I think it is better in a `.sty` file.

Comment: Use `\centering`, not `\center`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `\RequirePackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}` just before the `\endinput`
command of your `.cls` file.

The reason is that:

\RequirePackage is usually called in `.sty` files (in packages more general). Packages has to be called after \documentclass... And thus, packages (like `babel` here) will take care of previous defined commands, but documentclass has no reason to do it and has no checks about it.